# Why is the time complexity of the following code O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, brute-force

The Time Complexity of the below code is O(n) , But I'm not convinced , my answer is O(n^2).

```
    public static void fun(int n, int arr[]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (; i < n; i++) {
        while (j < n && arr[i] < arr[j])
            j++;

    }
}
```

**can somebody explain why the time complexity is O(n)?**

Comment: `j++` is created once, before any loops. So it stays intact throughout the inner loops and doesnt start over at `0`. The first call of the inner loop yields for example `n` iterations. But then, any other subsequent call of the inner loop yields no iterations at all. Put in some small example values and execute it by hand, line by line and you will immediately realize.

Comment: Well it is `O(n)`, if you work out the logic on paper.

Comment: The inner loop can have more than one iteration (per iteration of the outer loop), but in total, `j++` cannot execute more than `n` times. The evaluation of the `while` condition could happen up to 2n times in total, so all-in-all still O(n)

Comment: Can you add why you think this is O(N^2)? Using some algorithm analysis (and not just looking at two loops as a reason)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments state I also think it is `O(n)`.

An algorithm similar to yours with `O(n^2)` would be:

```java
public static void fun(int n, int arr[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < n; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < n && arr[i] < arr[j]) {
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

That can be simplified to:

```java
public static void fun(int n, int arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

The main difference is that the `j` is instantiated only once in your example.
Maybe this already helps in seeing why that makes your example `O(n)`.